# Clean Url Codeigniter

Tags: url, codeigniter

I want to clear my url with codeigniter, I have these types of urls: 
     `www.ggg.com/index.php/page/8/name.html`
and I want to trasform these like 
    `www.ggg.com/index.php/name.html` or      `www.ggg.com/name.html`

Is this possible modifying the file route.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the routes.php file and add the line:
    $route['name'] = "page/8/name";
This is all explained in the docs: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
To remove the index.php you will need a .htaccess file. There is an example in the ci docs or google it and you will find loads of tutorials. I'm sure there are even some examples here.

Comment: there is a problem when I write this rule in route.php: $route['page/index/:num/:any']='$2' it doesn't work, codeigniter said me "Page not fuond " when I write the url "www.ggg.com/index2.php/page/index/8/name.html"

Comment: You've got it the wrong way around. The array key is the URL that you want to see, in your case www.ggg.com/name and the array value is the controller/method that you actually want to use. Your problem is that the method you want to use requires an id as a parameter that is not fixed. The only thing I could suggest is to store (maybe temporarilly) the id in a session and then retrieve it when you need it. That way you could route "name" to "page/index" and it should all work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Actually to get rid of the `index.php` you need to edit out the `index.php` file from config.php (in your config folder inside application).

.htaccess for clean urls:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and to get rid of the `.html` just eliminate that 'suffix' again in the `config/config.php` file.

That should be all you need, the `.html` ending is just for *show*

As far as turning something like `page/8/name` into `name`, I would think twice about how that would work, your page or 8 most likely mean something, so your `name` would have to have code making it unique.  My guess is that page = 8 is the value, and the name is just for the friendly url look.

Comment: I agree about being careful about routing but the question was asking whether or not it was possible - which it is. We weren't asked if we thought it was a good idea!!

Comment: yes 8 is a id and name is something just for firendly url look

Comment: @Pierluigi Ballatore - If that is the case as I assumed, make sure to test if this type of change in URI will not upset the traversal of your website/app.